# Phonegap android studio plugin firebase-messaging build error

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I have made a project on phonegap.
I can compile and build apk in android studio without problem.
When I added a plugin for firebase messaging (that include google services) I get a compilation error (this error was not present 1 month ago).

the error is :

```
Error: Program type already present: 
android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable
```

Since 3 weeks I am searching for various solutions without any result.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the build.gradle(Module.app)

firebase-messaging already installs google-services to project

you should remove the last line of build.gradle(Module.app) which is something like

```
apply 'google-services-xxx'
```

Hope it helps!
add your build.gradle code to question